# How to optimize a JPQ JOIN query to run faster

Tags: java, sql, performance, hibernate, jpa

I have big performance issue in my JPA application. Suppose I have 3 entities:

```
class TaskResult {
    Task task;
}

class Task {
    User user;
}

class User {
    Long id;
}
```

Now, I want to get list of all TaskResults for one specific userId, there query will be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TaskResult r WHERE r.task.user.id = :id
```

And for over 10000 records it's too slow! Is there any other workaround?

Comment: It is JPA way, In my project, I create `view` in `database` and I bind this view with read only  `Entity`. It will get better performance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Try restricting the SELECT clause to `TaskResult` only and use explicit JOINs:

   ```
    SELECT tr 
    FROM TaskResult tr 
    JOIN tr.task t
    JOIN t.user u
    WHERE u.id = :id
   ```
2. Turn all [EAGER associations into LAZY ones](http://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/) and use FETCH on a query-basis.
3. Make sure there's an index on all Foreign Keys (`Task.task_result_id` and `User.task_id`)
4. Try running an SQL query an see if it's that slow too. If the SQL is slow, then Hibernate can't get any faster.
5. Try selecting fewer columns from `TaskResult` and use a projection instead.
6. You say there are 10,000 rows, but you surely don't need to display that many entities into the UI. Try using [keyset pagination](http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) which scales better than the default OFFSET pagination (supported by most JPA implementations).

Comment: 7. Replace the TaskRunner words to TaskResult in the 1st and 5th recommendation ;)